# Regex to match Down-Level Logon Name

Tags: regex, windows

I want to validate the Down-Level Logon Name entered by user. Any Idea?

Here is the Down-Level Logon Name format given:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: The specs don't really say what characters are allowed, or whether any part can be empty. The only thing that seems mandatory is the backslash, in which case this regex would suffice: `.*\\.*`

Comment: Maybe `[A-Z]+\\[\w.-]+`? Biffen is correct though, there is no info for allowed characters.

Answer (score 5):

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380525%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states, it is made of *NetBIOS domain name\User account name*.

[NetBIOS domain name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264/en-us) has some limitations:

> NetBIOS domain names can contain all alphanumeric characters except for the extended characters that are listed in the "Disallowed characters" section. Names can contain a period, but names cannot start with a period.
>
> Minimum name length 1 character. Maximum name length 15 characters.

That can represented with `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.]{0,14}`

[User account name](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx) also has some limitations:

> Logon names can be up to 104 characters. However, it isn't practical to use logon names that are longer than 64 characters.
>
> Logon names can't contain certain characters. Invalid characters are " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >
>
> Logon names can contain all other special characters, including spaces, periods, dashes, and underscores. But it's generally not a good idea to use spaces in account names.

That can be represented with `[^"/\\\[\]:;|=,+*?<>]{1,104}`

As it says nothing about minimal length I put 1 char there. I haven't met system, that allows empty user account name.

Finally, together it creates `[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9.]{0,14}\\[^"/\\\[\]:;|=,+*?<>]{1,104}` to match *NetBIOS domain name\User account name*.

---

However those are all technical limits, which are rarely used in real life. For instance  `.` in NetBIOS domain name is highly discouraged as well as `space` in User account name. Common maximum length of user account is 64 not 104 and on older Windows like 2000 it is even 20.

More realistic could be `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15}\\[a-zA-Z0-9._-]{1,64}`, but that's up to you.